# Rotate dimline label to horizontal

Tags: horizontal-alignment, labels

I want to rotate a label for my dimline to always be horizontal without having to calculate the rotation angle since they are numerous.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikz-dimline}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[inner sep=0pt] (im) at (0,0) 
{\includegraphics[scale=1]{example-image}};
\dimline[color = white, 
     line style = {line width = 0.7},
     label style = {anchor = south, fill = none }] 
         {(-1.2,-1.3)}
         {(2,1.6)}
         {$w$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: MWE]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One has to tell Ti*k*Z not to slope.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikz-dimline}
\tikzset{no slope/.code={\pgfslopedattimefalse}}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[inner sep=0pt] (im) at (0,0) 
{\includegraphics[scale=1]{example-image}};
\dimline[color = white, 
     line style = {line width = 0.7},
     label style = {above=2mm, fill = none,no slope}] 
         {(-1.2,-1.3)}
         {(2,1.6)}
         {$w$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for this approach, really easy to implement and change the anchor points change the position of the label!

Comment: check! sorry for the delay.

Answer (score 4):

like this:

[image]

but this is drawn by pure `tikz`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,quotes}
%\usepackage{tikz-dimline}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[inner sep=0pt] (im) at (0,0)
{\includegraphics[scale=1]{example-image}};
\draw[color = white,{Bar[]Stealth[]}-{Stealth[]Bar[]}, line width = 0.7]
    (-1.2,-1.3) to ["$w$"] (2,1.6);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```